# why the difference between numpy matrix and numpy array when selecting element

Tags: numpy

I have a calculated matrix

```
from numpy import matrix
vec=matrix([[  4.79263398e-01+0.j        ,  -2.94883960e-14+0.34362808j,           
     5.91036823e-01+0.j        ,  -2.06730654e-14+0.41959935j,
      -3.20298698e-01+0.08635809j,  -5.97136351e-02+0.22325523j],
    [  9.45394208e-14+0.34385164j,   4.78941900e-01+0.j        ,
       1.07732017e-13+0.41891016j,   5.91969770e-01+0.j        ,
      -6.06877417e-02-0.2250884j ,   3.17803028e-01+0.08500215j],
    [  4.63795513e-01-0.00827114j,  -1.15263719e-02+0.33287485j,
      -2.78282097e-01-0.20137267j,  -2.81970922e-01-0.1980647j ,
       9.26109539e-02-0.38428445j,   5.12483437e-01+0.j        ],
    [ -1.15282610e-02+0.33275927j,   4.63961516e-01-0.00826978j,
      -2.84077490e-01-0.19723838j,  -2.79429184e-01-0.19984041j,
      -4.42104809e-01+0.25708681j,  -2.71973825e-01+0.28735795j],
    [  4.63795513e-01+0.00827114j,   1.15263719e-02+0.33287485j,
      -2.78282097e-01+0.20137267j,   2.81970922e-01-0.1980647j ,
       2.73235786e-01+0.28564581j,  -4.44053596e-01-0.25584307j],
    [  1.15282610e-02+0.33275927j,   4.63961516e-01+0.00826978j,
       2.84077490e-01-0.19723838j,  -2.79429184e-01+0.19984041j,
       5.11419878e-01+0.j        ,  -9.22028113e-02-0.38476356j]])
```

I want to get 2nd row, 3rd column element

```
  vec[1][2]
  IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

and slicing works well

```
  vec[1,2]
  (1.07732017e-13+0.41891015999999998j)
```

My first question why first way does not work in this case? it worked before when I used it.

Second question is: the result of slicing is an array, how to make it an complex value without bracket? My experience was using

```
 vec[1,2][0]
```

but again it is not working here.

I tried to do everything on numpy array at begining, those methods that do not work on numpy matrix work on numpy array. Why there are such differences?

Comment: Did you look at the `vec[1]` and its shape?  Remember `vec[1][2]` first does `x = vec[1]` followed by `x[2]`.  That's two python indexing steps.  `vec[1,2]` is one indexing step.  Pay close attention to the shape when indexing, especially with arrays.

Comment: It's one of the quirks of the `matrix` class and incidentally one of the reasons I strongly recommend against using it. Your double indexing works as expected with `arrays` because they behave like nested lists in that respect. `matrix`es do not, they stubbornly return something 2D. Btw. when dealing with arrays `[1, 2]` is prefereable to `[1][2]` because as  @hpaulj explains the latter creates an unnecessary intermediate.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference is that a `matrix` is always 2d, always. (This is supposed to be familiar to MATLAB users.)

```
In [85]: mat = np.matrix('1,2;3,4')
In [86]: mat
Out[86]: 
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
In [87]: mat.shape
Out[87]: (2, 2)
In [88]: mat[1]
Out[88]: matrix([[3, 4]])
In [89]: _.shape
Out[89]: (1, 2)
```

Selecting a row of `mat` returns a matrix - a 1 row one.  It should be clear that it cannot be indexed again with `[1]`.

Indexing with the tuple returns a scalar:

```
In [90]: mat[1,1]
Out[90]: 4
In [91]: type(_)
Out[91]: numpy.int32
```

As a general rule operations on a `np.matrix` returns a matrix or a scalar, not a `np.ndarray`.

The other key point is that `mat[1][1]` is not one `numpy` operation.  It is two, a `mat[1]` followed by another `[1]`.  Imagine yourself to be a Python interpreter without any special knowledge of `numpy`.  How would you evaluate that expression?

Now for the complex question:

```
In [92]: mat = np.matrix('1+3j, 2;-2, 2+1j')
In [93]: mat
Out[93]: 
matrix([[ 1.+3.j,  2.+0.j],
        [-2.+0.j,  2.+1.j]])
In [94]: mat[1,1]
Out[94]: (2+1j)
In [95]: type(_)
Out[95]: numpy.complex128
```

As expected the tuple index has returned a scalar numpy element.  `()` is just part of `numpy`s way of displaying a complex number.

We can use `item` to extra python equivalent, but the display still uses ()

```
In [96]: __.item()
Out[96]: (2+1j)
In [97]: type(_)
Out[97]: complex

In [98]: 1+3j
Out[98]: (1+3j)
```

`mat` has `A` property that gives the array equivalent.  But notice the shapes.

```
In [99]: mat.A        # a 2d array
Out[99]: 
array([[ 1.+3.j,  2.+0.j],
       [-2.+0.j,  2.+1.j]])
In [100]: mat.A1         # a 1d array
Out[100]: array([ 1.+3.j,  2.+0.j, -2.+0.j,  2.+1.j])
In [101]: mat[1].A
Out[101]: array([[-2.+0.j,  2.+1.j]])
In [102]: mat[1].A1
Out[102]: array([-2.+0.j,  2.+1.j])
```

Sometimes this behavior of `matrix` is handy.  For example `np.sum` acts like the `array` `keepdims=True`:

```
In [108]: np.sum(mat,1)
Out[108]: 
matrix([[ 3.+3.j],
        [ 0.+1.j]])

In [110]: np.sum(mat.A,1, keepdims=True)
Out[110]: 
array([[ 3.+3.j],
       [ 0.+1.j]])
```